# “pico TTS Engine has Stopped" error

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am writing a codes using TextToSpeech. It went well throughout the codes, however, every single time I exit the codes, it gives me the error message saying that 'Unfortunately, pico TTS engine has stopped." This only happens when I exit the code. I am wondering why this happens. Thanks.

Comment: This question still needs an answer.  I am getting the problem but only on API 21 emulator.  Calling shutdown or not makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this message too whenever I exited my code or whenever I called `textToSpeech.shutdown();`

I solved this problem by deleting my AVD (Android Virtual Device Nexus_6_API_23) and creating a new one.  The new AVD worked without giving any error message.

Apparently this was a problem with my AVD and not a problem with my code or the TTS engine.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. every time I changed activity or exit the program I got “pico TTS Engine has Stopped". I changed the api from 23 to 24 and used android 7.0 and the error have gone.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the issue at [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/svox/+/6fbadb666c32920cf36e646f3c00aab1ad49cdf6)

> ```
> CTS cases fail due to NE in SVOX TTS library
>
> Failed CTS cases:
> android.speech.tts.cts.TextToSpeechTest#testSpeak
> android.speech.tts.cts.TextToSpeechTest#testSpeakStop
> android.speech.tts.cts.TextToSpeechTest#testSynthesizeToFile
>
> We can also reproduce this NE by following steps:
> 1. Go to Accessibility Settings
> 2. Select Text to speech output
> 3. Click play
>
> Analysis: Exception occurs due to calculation of
> picokpr_getAttrValArrInt32(...) is incorrect. The logic here intends
> to clear the MSB and return the rest of the bits. We found if library
> compiled in Android N environment the result of comparison operation
> is different from library compiled in Android O environment. In
> Android O, actual returne value doesn't process the value and returns
> as it is. This causes invalid pointer access and hence native
> exception due to segmentation fault.
>
> Solution: Changed to use bitwise shift instead.
>
> Bug: 64204643 Test: After applying this patch, CTS cases can pass and
> exception can be fixed.
>
> Change-Id: Ife3137225ecf9667df62321472420fab6ab88d2e
> ```